# How to make case insensitive PostgreSQL using JPA query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am new to JPA Criteria builder concept, I am using PostgreSQL and JPA Query.I got this query SELECT id, full_name, email FROM nurses WHERE(lower(sender) LIKE '%bar%' and lower(receiver) LIKE '%bar%').but how to convert it to JPA Criteria builder.

```
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            System.out.println(entityManager + " Conected");
            CriteriaQuery<sourceTracking> cq = cb.createQuery(sourceTracking.class);
            Root<sourceTracking> data1 = cq.from(sourceTracking.class);
            cq.where(cb.like(data1.<String>get("sender"), "%"+sender+"%"),cb.like(data1.<String>get("receiver"), "%"+receiver+"%");
            cq.select(data1);
            TypedQuery<sourceTracking> tquery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
            sourselList = tquery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CriteriaBuilder.lower()` will do what you want.

e.g.

```
cb.like(cb.lower(data1.get("sender")), "%" + sender + "%")
```

or, to make your pattern lowercase too:

```
cb.like(cb.lower(data1.get("sender")), cb.lower(cb.literal("%" + sender + "%")))
```